# Display only Sub-Categories in Category Module in Opencart

Tags: php, html, opencart

Is there a way, or an extension, that will modify the Category module so it only displays the current top level category page's sub-categories.

For example, if I am on the "Laptops & Desktops" category page, the sidebar module would only list the sub-categories associated with "Laptops & Desktops" category, such as "Macs" and "PCs" with the main heading "Laptops & Desktops" (And not list or show any of the other top level categories).

Comment: What if the products are added to the parent categories?

Comment: we have sub categories in all parent categories

Comment: but what to do if the products are added assigned to only the parent categories like  "Laptops & Desktops" and not to it's sub-categories like  "Macs" and "PCs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `foreach` section in `catalog/controller/module/category.php` in the following way to show only the sub-categories in left column.

```
    $cur_category_id = $this->data['category_id']; // new code 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $children_data = array();

        $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $children_data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data) . ')' : ''),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
            );  

            if($cur_category_id && $cur_category_id == $category['category_id']){
                $this->data['heading_title'] =  $category['name'];
                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                    'children'    => array(),
                    'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
                );
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'filter_category_id'  => $category['category_id'],
            'filter_sub_category' => true
        );
        /*
        $this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
            'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data) . ')' : ''),
            'children'    => $children_data,
            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
        );  */
    }
```

**Note:** As I added comment to your question earlier, only the sub categories will be shown and there will not be any option to select the products added to parent categories.

Have a nice day :) !!

Comment: That works well, but it showing same child categories for all parent categories. i need something like this [link](http://www.ukplanettools.co.uk/power-tools.php) . Please check the category pages.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the whole foreach section. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But please check this [link](http://microsolutionsind.com/demo/demo.html).  Here you can get my desired content.